# FrescoImageViewer: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme

Tags: android, fresco

I am trying to use fresco image viewer, 
But I am getting this error, when click listener is being executed

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:355)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:324)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:285)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDialog.setContentView(AppCompatDialog.java:83)
at android.support.v7.app.AlertController.installContent(AlertController.java:225)
at android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.onCreate(AlertDialog.java:257)
at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:397)
at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:298)
at com.stfalcon.frescoimageviewer.ImageViewer.show(ImageViewer.java:61)
at com.stfalcon.frescoimageviewer.ImageViewer$Builder.show(ImageViewer.java:435)
at com.unobridge.www.unobridgepartner.view.service_detail.adapters.QueryImageGalleryAdapter$1.onClick(QueryImageGalleryAdapter.java:67)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5207)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21177)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5441)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:738)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:628)
```

And Code in Adapter, Adapter has the context of the activity, which is again passed to FrescoImageViewer :

```
holder.simpleDraweeView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d(TAG, holder.getAdapterPosition()+" ");
            new ImageViewer.Builder<>(context,fileMaps)
                    .setFormatter(new ImageViewer.Formatter<FileMap>(){
                        @Override
                        public String format(FileMap fileMap) {
                            return fileMap.getUrls().get(0).getUrl();
                        }
                    })
                    .show();
        }
    });
```

Activity Code :

```
package com.unobridge.www.unobridgepartner.view.service_detail.activities;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.databinding.DataBindingUtil;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.DefaultItemAnimator;
import android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.facebook.drawee.backends.pipeline.Fresco;
import com.unobridge.www.unobridgepartner.R;
import com.unobridge.www.unobridgepartner.databinding.ActivityQueryImageGalleryBinding;
import com.unobridge.www.unobridgepartner.model.FileMap;
import com.unobridge.www.unobridgepartner.model.Ticket;
import com.unobridge.www.unobridgepartner.view.service_detail.adapters.QueryImageGalleryAdapter;
import com.unobridge.www.unobridgepartner.viewmodel.service_detail.activities.QueryImageGalleryViewModel;

import java.util.List;

public class QueryImageGalleryActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TICKET_DATA = "ticket_data";
    private ActivityQueryImageGalleryBinding binding;
    private QueryImageGalleryViewModel queryImageGalleryViewModel;
    private QueryImageGalleryAdapter queryImageGalleryAdapter;

    private List<FileMap> fileMaps;

    public static Intent newIntent(Context context, Ticket ticket){
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, QueryImageGalleryActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(TICKET_DATA, ticket);
        return intent;
    }



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Ticket ticket = getIntent().getParcelableExtra(TICKET_DATA);


        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_query_image_gallery);
        queryImageGalleryViewModel = new QueryImageGalleryViewModel(getApplicationContext(), ticket);
        binding.setViewModel(queryImageGalleryViewModel);

        queryImageGalleryAdapter = new QueryImageGalleryAdapter(getApplicationContext(), ticket.getQueryImages());

        Fresco.initialize(this);

        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), 2);
        binding.queryImageRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        binding.queryImageRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        binding.queryImageRecyclerView.setAdapter(queryImageGalleryAdapter);


        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Query Image Gallery");


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                super.onBackPressed();
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the code of your activity

Comment: @SushobhNadiger Added please see

Comment: No , i meant the entire activity. Because the parent class of your activity could determine the problem.

Comment: My Activity runs well, Adapter runs well, But only when i click , it throws this error

Comment: Did you try searching for that error? What about the solutions don't you understand? The photo viewer isn't the problem

Comment: I know , But I posted this question , because somebody may have faced have this issue too

Comment: `      <activity android:name=".view.service_detail.activities.QueryImageGalleryActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity> `

Comment: Try to replace all `getApplicationContext()` with `QueryImageGalleryActivity.this `

Comment: @cricket_007 thanks it works like charm

Comment: @cricket_007 add it to the answer , i ll accept it

Comment: But what is the difference, Can you explain ? @cricket_007

Comment: i am implementing same image view in recycle view get the same error only use this view in layout no doing any thing up to now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the AppCompatActivity themes set to the context of the Activity, which it seems your application is not using

Replace all `getApplicationContext()` with `QueryImageGalleryActivity.this` (the current Activity / context)

Comment: @criclet_007  i am implementing same image view in recycle view get the same error only use this view in layout no doing any thing up to now

Comment: @Mehul please create a new post